# Caching of navigation properties in Entity Framework Core

Tags: caching, entity-framework-core, navigation-properties

There are several solutions for caching in EF Core. But I have a question about a specific solution.

Below I have an order entity with a normal property and a navigation one. The navigation property is of type `Customer` which is a value which rarely changes. I want to cache all existing customers from database in memory (because there are not so much data).

```cs
public class Order
{
    prop int Id { get; set; }
    prop Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

The question is about my query. In a command query I would include `Customer` like this:

```cs
dbContext.Order
         .Include(c => c.Customer)
         .First();
```

Is there a solution that Entity Framework Core is using the cache instead a join for the included customer? Or is my query required to write special code for it?

Comment: Just an idea: attach customers to ChangeTracker and remove `Include`. EF Core should fixup navigation properties in this case.